# How to get particular property from item selected in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have the following:

```xml
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
ItemsSource="{Binding items}" DisplayMemberPath="s"/>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedItem.s}"/>
```

This is definition of `SelectedItem`

```
public MemEntity SelectedItem {get; set;}
```

`MemEntity` is a class containing

```
public String s {get; get;}.
```

Basically, I want s of the selected item to be shown in the `TextBlock` (same property as shown in `ListBox`). This doesn't work, so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The view is unaware that selected item has changed. look into using `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: I see. I'll implement the interface and raise the event.

Comment: Are you applying MVVM?

Comment: Yes.(10 more to go :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<TextBlock ... Text="{Binding ElementName=items, Path=SelectedItem.s}" />
```

then add a name to your ListBox as,

```
  <ListBox x:Name="items" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding items}" DisplayMemberPath="s"/>
```

Comment: No need for NotifyPropertyChanged when using MVVM, right? Because I couldn't get this to work (or update maybe).

Comment: you need it for binding

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple way to do this. One option has already been provided in another answer that focusing on achieving the desired functionality by binding to a view element. Here is another option.

The view is unaware that selected item has changed. look into using `INotifyPropertyChanged`

You can create a base ViewModel to encapsulate the repeated functionality

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged = delegate { };

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Have the view models inherit from this base class in order for the view to be aware of changes when binding.

```
public class ItemsViewModel : ViewModelBase {

    public ItemsViewModel() {
        items = new ObservableCollection<MemEntity>();
    }

    private MemEntity selectedItem;
    public MemEntity SelectedItem {
        get { return selectedItem; }
        set {
            if (selectedItem != value) {
                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(); //this will raise the property changed event.
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MemEntity> items { get; set; }
}
```

The view will now be aware when ever the `SelectedItem` property changes and will update the view accordingly.

Comment: Actually, I can't get anything to update. Although I added bindings like in the previous answer as well as INotifyPropertyChanged.